# Recovering chat history

Tags: gmail

I have deleted my chat history of mail and deleted it from trash as well. I am unable to recover it. PLease help me out. It is very important for me.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Chat messages and email messages are handled differently in Gmail, but at last, both kind of messages can't be recovered after they are permanently deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, messages permanently deleted in Gmail can not be recovered.

Someone has already faced this problem and there is an expert reply on this. See [Gmail Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/96g1CYJHjyY).

**Edit:**

Gmail chat messages don't go to trash, they are deleted permanently just after the user confirm to delete them.

Comment: Gmail chat messages don't go to trash, they are deleted permanently just after the user confirm to delete them. By the other hand the link points to a thread about a broader situation.